# Admin-on-rest- How to Mix components in Resource and Show/Edit modes?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

Now I am purely following example of Admin-on-rest (https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Resource.html).

When it opens List (with DataGrid) or Show/Edit, I want to add additional components to that page. Some analytics (using Cards), Google Maps module (https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react), Photo and etc.

I want them responsive and "floating". As different components. Not the same one.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [docs on how to setup a custom layout](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Theming.html#using-a-custom-layout). As everything in `admin-on-rest` is also just react you can [modify it nearly in every way you like](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html). But notice that this requires a decent knowledge of `react`and `redux` and probably other libraries that admin-on-rest uses under the hood. I would first try to override the standard layout. Inside your custom layout component you could e.g render any components you like at any places.

Also if you want to customize only a certain ListView you can just pass your own component to the `<Ressource>` component like this:

```js
<Admin restClient={jsonServerRestClient('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')}>
    <Resource name="posts" list={MyCustomPostList} /* other views */ />
</Admin>
```

And then in `/src/MyCustomPostList.js` something like that:

```js
class MyCustomPostList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {myOwnProp, ...otherProps} = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                // render your own components here
                <AnyComponent myOwnProp={myOwnProp} />
                <AGoogleMapsComponent />

                // render the normal <List> component
                <List {...otherProps}>
                    <Datagrid>
                        <TextField source="id" />
                        <TextField source="title" />
                        <TextField source="body" />
                    </Datagrid>
                 </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As this is not a trivial task you will not find anybody to present you a detailed solution here. You can start with the links i added and try it yourself. If you encounter any concrete problems on your way there you can come back and ask a concrete question about this.

If you want it to be responsive and floating you can use e.g. flexbox or any grid css framework.

I hope that this is a starting point for you.

Comment: Such clean solution... Thank you very much!!

Comment: @hitchnsmile You can thank me best by upvoting and/or marking this as the accepted answer. ;-)

Comment: Could you help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888695/admin-on-rest-how-to-sync-other-components-with-query-filtered-from-list/44889274#44889274